# SciKit's BayesianGaussianMixture.predict(...) function returns an int64 datatype which seems wrong

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mixture-model

I've trained a [`BayesianGaussianMixture`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.BayesianGaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.BayesianGaussianMixture.fit) model on `float64` data generated from two `np.random.multivariate_normal` guassians.

The weights, means, and covariances all match closely to the original distribution. As far as I can tell it got trained correctly. I did *not* pass it any labels during fitting, only my data points.

When I call `BayesianGaussianMixture.predict(X)` it returns an `int64` data type, which always seems to be 1.

I was expecting `predict(X)` to produce the PDF (probability density function) at `X`

> Is that assumption valid? What should I expect from `predict(X)`?
>
> Based on comments, the right question to ask might be: "How to I compute the PDF (probability density function) at a certain point of the gaussian mixture distribution that was learned?"

Comment: Have you given any labels (`y`) during fitting? What is the data type for them?

Comment: Ah, I should have directly specified that I did not give it labels during fitting. And in fact I don't quite understand the purpose of labels in this context. I only want to come away with a distribution that fits my data that I can sample from. To sample from it I also need to be able to compute the PDF at a specific point. I'll be using Monte Carlo Rejection Sampling to sample from a uniform distribution under the distribution that fits my data.

Comment: I think this question may answer it for me, I had presumed that `predict()` would give me the PDF, but perhaps I just need to calculate it from the given weights & normals. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22871/efficient-sampling-of-a-mixture-model